# Riguardo alle congiunzioni e alla cacofonia

Tags: conjunctions

In spagnolo ci sono due congiunzioni copulative (**y**, **e**) e due congiunzioni disgiuntive (**o**, **u**). Normalmente usiamo **y** e **o**, però se il fonema immediatamente seguente è uguale dobbiamo usare **e** o **u** al fine di evitare la cacofonia risultante della coincidenza della congiunzione con la sillaba che segue. Una spiegazione più esaustiva in [questa pagina](https://www.thoughtco.com/pronunciation-based-changes-y-and-o-3078176) o in [questa risposta (che ha ispirato la domanda)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/42310/difference-between-o-and-u-to-say-or). Tuttavia, a titolo di esempio, si possono confrontare queste frasi:

> Esa vez fuimos siete **u** ocho, no recuerdo bien.

> In quel momento fummo sette **o** otto, non ricordo bene.

In italiano, non ci sono altre congiunzioni da usare in questi situazioni? Non c'è nessuna strategia per evitare la cacofonia nel secondo caso? Non fa alcun danno alle orecchie degli italiani ascoltare questo genere di cose?

Comment: No, abbiamo le orecchie molto robuste!  :)  Anche qui mi sono permesso qualche piccola correzione al tuo italiano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storicamente esiste la cosiddetta [*d eufonica*](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/d-eufonica-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) per evitare cacofonia. Cioè si usa *ed* invece di *e*, *od* invece di *o* e *ad* invece di *a* quando la vocale che segue immediatamente è uguale alla vocale della preposizione. Perciò *Luigi ed Enzo* e *vivo ad Amalfi* etc.

Tuttavia, come si può leggere nel link dell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano

> [L]’italiano contemporaneo è molto meno ostile allo iato di quanto lo fosse l’italiano letterario di base fiorentina; quindi è possibile fare a meno della d eufonica anche in caso di identità tra le vocali: *ho incontrato Luigi e Enzo*.

Cioè le combinazioni evitate dalla d eufonica sono percepite sempre meno come cacofoniche, e vengono normalmente usate nell'italiano parlato. Ironicamene io uso normalmente la d eufonica solo nello scritto...